# Find $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3^{\sin x}+2x+1}{\sin x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: limits

Find the value of $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3^{\sin x}+2x+1}{\sin x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

---

$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3^{\sin x}+2x+1}{\sin x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$
Since this is in $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form,so i applied L Hospital rule,
$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{3^{\sin x}\cos x\log 3+2}{\cos x-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}}$
But i am stuck here.

Comment: trigonometric terms won't matter, they will scarcely alter things when x approaches infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note** : In the denominator, when we take $x$ out of the square root, we will get $|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ Which will become = $-x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ (As $x$ is negative)

No need for LH here,

Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$, the given expression becomes:
$$\frac{{3^{\sin x} \over x} + 2 + \frac{1}{x}}{{\sin x \over x} + \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}$$
Now, applying the limit,
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac{{3^{\sin x} \over x} + 2 + \frac{1}{x}}{{\sin x \over x} + \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}=2$$